# AST node for accessing struct data members

Tags: c++, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, language-design

I just added C-style `struct` to my toy language, and I am not sure how to represent accesses to data members in my AST. I am considering something like

```
class StructProperty : public Expr {
    std::unique_ptr<Expr> parent_;
    std::string property_;
};
```

so that `getParent().data.foo = 42;` would be parsed as

```
AssignStmt:
-> rhs: IntegerLiteral
        -> value: 42
-> lvalue: StructProperty
           -> name: foo
           -> parent: StructProperty
                      -> name: data
                      -> parent: FuncCall
                                 -> name: getParent
                                 -> args: none
```

Does that make any sense? Is that how `struct` data members are typically represented in ASTs? Is there a better way?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: It might be reasonable to try and unify struct data members and fixed length array elements, assuming you intend to do those. In the end they both amount to a byte offset.

Comment: @Ryan1729 Is it something that is usually done at the AST level? If I combine these two expressions, I can no longer differentiate them when traversing the tree. Is that going to be an issue? I was considering unifying them when writing the linear IR later down the line, but I have not reached that point yet.

Comment: I’m not sure what is commonly done. However I suppose that for the purpose of having compile errors that can tell the difference between struct data members and array elements, it may be worth keeping the distinction around for a while. Whether you want to add a boolean or enum to the ast node class for this, or to have a separate class for each would largely be a style choice I think.